# Get Wishlist product collection in Controller of Custom module Magento2

Tags: magento2, php, module, wishlist

I am trying to get Wishlist product collection in Custom module controller for the new functionality. I searched in google and I got this:

Inject this class in your constructor:

```
protected $wishlistProvider;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Wishlist\Controller\WishlistProviderInterface $wishlistProvider
) {
    $this->wishlistProvider = $wishlistProvider;
    ...
}
```

and

```
$currentUserWishlist = $this->wishlistProvider->getWishlist();
if ($currentUserWishlist) {
    $wishlistItems = $currentUserWishlist->getItemCollection();
}
```

I have tried using this code. But its not working. I am getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Argument 3 passed to
>   namespace\modulename\Controller\Index\Index::__construct() must be an
>   instance of Magento\Wishlist\Controller\WishlistProviderInterface,
>   none given, called in
>   /var/www/project_name/var/generation/namespace/modulename/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php
>   on line 14

Please suggest me a way to do this. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Have you remove var folder?

Comment: Just I have removed generation folder in var. I have to remove var folder fully??

Comment: Try `bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Answer (score 0):

In other way you can  get wishlist items collection.

Use  factory **`Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Item\CollectionFactory`** for getting *wishlist product collection*  and filter  that by `addCustomerIdFilter($customerId)`

```
protected $_currentUserWishlistCollectionFactory ;
protected $_Customersession;
public function __construct(
       \Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Item\CollectionFactory $currentUserWishlistCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $Customersession,
    ) {
    ....
    $this->_Customersession = $Customersession;
        $this->_currentUserWishlistCollectionFactory = $currentUserWishlistCollectionFactory;
....

    }

public function getcurrentUserWishlistItems(){

    $collection = $this->_currentUserWishlistCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addCustomerIdFilter($this->_Customersession->getCustomerId());
    return $collection;

}
```

Comment: Where I have to put this code in order to get the customer wishlist collection. I want to download the customer wishlist collection as a CSV file. Can you guide me on that?

Comment: As of now, I'm able to download the sample data as a CSV file. I have referred this URL: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/287976/how-to-create-a-excel-file-in-custom-module/287978?noredirect=1#comment431521_287978

Answer (score 0):

Try to compile your codes:

```
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Appears to me, that your error will be solved with this.