# How to Create a excel file in custom module?

Tags: magento2, module, adminhtml, uicomponent, csv

I want to create an excel format file for download in Magento 2

```
<item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add a new Guest</item>
            <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/newAction</item>
        </item>

        <item name="xml" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="name" xsi:type="string">xml</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Excel Download</item>

            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/export/gridToXls</item>
        </item>
    </item>
```

[image]

I have the skeleton for my GridToXls action here:

```
class GridToXls extends Action
 {

  public function execute(){
    //do
   }
 }
```

> How do I create and prepare the excel file for download in a Magento 2
>   custom module?

Comment: Please correct your question. You've asked for excel download, but you've accepted an answer that downloads as CSV. May be that's the requirement for you, but it   will mislead others, like I reached here. Excel and CSV are not same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Magento 2 Native, One php class **\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory** is used for create csv and download CSV by magento way. **create() function in FileFactory.php** is used for create CSV file.
There are many another way to download CSV file using Core PHP script but its not best way to use within Magento Coding standard.
You can write CSV and download a CSV file using just simple below code snippet in your controller file,    **namespace {your vendor}\CSV\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;**

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class Export extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
    ) {
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->_fileFactory = $fileFactory;
        $this->directory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::VAR_DIR);
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $name = date('m_d_Y_H_i_s');
        $filepath = 'export/custom' . $name . '.csv';
        $this->directory->create('export');
        /* Open file */
        $stream = $this->directory->openFile($filepath, 'w+');
        $stream->lock();
        $columns = $this->getColumnHeader();
        foreach ($columns as $column) {
            $header[] = $column;
        }
        /* Write Header */
        $stream->writeCsv($header);

        $products[] = array(1,'Test 1','test 1',100);
        $products[] = array(2,'Test 2','test 2',299);

        foreach ($products as $item) {
            $itemData = [];
            $itemData[] = $item[0];
            $itemData[] = $item[1];
            $itemData[] = $item[2];
            $itemData[] = $item[3];
            $stream->writeCsv($itemData);
        }

        $content = [];
        $content['type'] = 'filename'; // must keep filename
        $content['value'] = $filepath;
        $content['rm'] = '1'; //remove csv from var folder

        $csvfilename = 'Product.csv';
        return $this->_fileFactory->create($csvfilename, $content, DirectoryList::VAR_DIR);

    }

    /* Header Columns */
    public function getColumnHeader() {
        $headers = ['Id','Product name','SKU','Price'];
        return $headers;
    }
}
```

When you run controller action you can download CSV file using just Magento straight forward way.
Using the above way you can download CSV file using Magento 2 Way.**you can customize on your requirement**

Comment: Thanks, Shafeel Sha.  It's working for me

Comment: @NiteshKumarSingh  your welcome , Happy coding :)

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to namespace\models\Controller\Adminhtml\Export\GridToXls::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context, instance of Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager given, called in /tyresnmore/20190705151145/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93

Comment: run on server getting error

Comment: please run baisc commands >

Comment: @ShafeelSha I have used your code in controller file but couldn't able to download CSV. Please guide me

Comment: @siva  facing any errors

Comment: @ShafeelSha, No, I'm not getting any errors. What I did is I have put your code into the path app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Export.php and I'm not sure there after. How to get the CSV file downloaded? Please help me

Comment: When you run controller action you can download CSV file using just Magento straight forward way.
Using the above way you can download CSV file using Magento 2 Way.

Comment: Yes. Now, I can download the file. Thanks.

Comment: I want to download the customer wishlist data as a CSV file. How can I get it? Can you guide me on that?

Comment: Hi @siva, please comment me the question link below

Comment: @ShafeelSha, Here's the URL: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/299504/magento2-3-how-to-download-the-customer-wishlist-collection-as-a-csv-file

Comment: @ShafeelSha can you share an example for xls file not csv.?