# How to collect customer data who has added the product to wishlist?

Tags: magento2.3, customer, controllers, wishlist, admin-controller

I have a requirement that is collect customers data like wishlist, address and send them to another server using **SFTP**. These all should be programmatically.

> Could anyone please guide me on this?

**Your help will be greatly appreciated!**

Answer (score 0):

```
class WishlistLoadItems extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Wishlist\Model\Wishlist $wishlist,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface $adrs,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->wishlist = $wishlist;
        $this->adrs = $adrs;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        if ($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {

            $customer_id = $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
            $wishlist_collection = $this->wishlist->loadByCustomerId($customer_id, true)->getItemCollection();

            wishlist_data=[];
            // get whishlist pdt name

            foreach ($wishlist_collection as $item) {
               // $wishlist_data[] = $item->getProduct()->getData(); // to get product datas
                $wishlist_data[] = $item->getProduct()->getName(); // to get whishlist product name
            }

            // to get user adrs
            $customer = $this->adrs->getById($customer_id);
            //$addresses = $customer->getAddresses(); // to get address array
            $billingAddress = $customer->getDefaultBilling();  // to get biling adrs


            if(wishlist_data) 
            {

                  // do your logic  if customer whishlist not empty
            }else
            {
                // do your logic  if customer whishlist is empty
            }


        } 
    }
}
```

It helps to load logged customer whishlist product datas and adrs

Comment: Thanks. What If I want it to store as a CSV file?

Comment: Please follow this 
 https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/287976/how-to-create-a-excel-file-in-custom-module/287978#287978