# Magento2.3: How to download the customer wishlist collection as a CSV file?

Tags: magento2.3, wishlist, customer-collection

I have a requirement that is collecting wish-list data and download/store them as a CSV file.

As of now, I have referred the below URL and tried getting the sample CSV file downloaded.

[How to Create a excel file in custom module?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/287976/how-to-create-a-excel-file-in-custom-module/287978?noredirect=1#comment431590_287978)

However, I'm not sure how to get the wishlist collection?

Could anyone please help me with that?

Comment: You want wish list data for all customer in a single csv or individual csv for every customer...

Comment: Hi @PartabSaifuddinZakir, I want the wish list data as a single CSV file. Please help me

Comment: You mean all customer wish-list data in a single csv file ?

Comment: @Partab Yes, I need all customer wishlist data in a single file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here You Go...

I installed and tested this extension, if you want all your customer wish list data in a single `CSV`, you should install this extension [Import Export Wishlist Item](https://marketplace.magento.com/bsscommerce-wishlist-item-import-export.html).

**HOW TO USE IT**

Go to `SYSTEM > Export Wishlist Item`

[image]

And you'll see this page:

[image]

Select `Entity Type = Wishlist Item`

Select `Export By = All`

Hit `Continue`

You will get a CSV file with all customer's wishlist data. You can do much more with this extension.

Thank You.

Comment: Thanks. I will check this. How can I do it programmatically?

Comment: It's a simple module you can check it's code to know that, if you need any help please let me know.

Comment: Sure. Tell me one thing, What I want is the wishlist collection should be store as a CSV file automatically like CRON. Is it possible for to make using this extension?

Comment: @Siva Of course , you should customize this extension as per your need, besides making new module from scratch, Also free approve this answer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out this extension. It's really helpful for me and I have got some idea now.

Comment: @Siva I'm glad to hear that, please approve my answer to finish this subject.

Comment: Sure, I have approved. In addition, can you give me some idea on the customisation? Please refer my question and share your knowledge that will be add me some though process on the idea which I have.

Comment: Share question link...

Comment: Here is the link to question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/300256/magento2-3-how-to-create-a-csv-and-json-file