# Magento2.3: How to create a CSV and JSON file?

Tags: magento2.3, csv, json, customer-collection

I have successfully got the wishlist collection of customer by referring the below link:

https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/get-wishlist-collection-of-customer-by-customer-id-magento-2/

Now, I have to create the wishlist collection as a CSV file. Since, I'm new to this, I have no idea where to start.

Could anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

If you got all wishlist collection, and create you CSV, you have to do similar something like this below, also I've did this to get product collection in a CSV, you have to customize this code according to your collection data:

```
$_filename = 'WishlistCollection.csv';
$file = fopen(YOUR_FILE_PATH . '/' . $_filename, 'w');
fputcsv($file, self::HEADINGS, ",", '"');

foreach ($collection as $_wishllist) {
    fputcsv($file, array(   
        $_wishllist->getData1(),
        $_wishllist->getData2(),
        $_wishllist->getData3()
    ), ",", '"');
}
fclose($file);
```

Comment: Thanks. Glad to know that you have got the product collection as a CSV. My query is that on after I collect the wishlist data, where I have to customize in order to get a CSV file?

Comment: please paste you whole code.

Answer (score 0):

Below script will help you out to directly download the wishlist details within csv for respective customer.

```
$csvGenerate = array();
$csvGenerate[] = array("Product Name","Product ID");

$customerId = 'respective_customer_id'; //CUSTOMER_ID
$wishlistCollection = $block->getWishlistByCustomerId($customerId);
if(count($wishlistCollection)) {
    foreach ($wishlistCollection as $_item) {
      $temp1 = array();
      $temp1[] = $_item->getProduct()->getName();
      $temp1[] = $_item->getProduct()->getId();
      $csvGenerate[] = $temp1;
    }
} else {
  echo __("No Item found in your wishlist");
}

function array2csv(array &$array)
{
   if (count($array) == 0) {
     return null;
   }
   ob_start();
   $df = fopen("php://output", 'w');

   foreach ($array as $row) {
      fputcsv($df, $row);
   }
   fclose($df);
   return ob_get_clean();
}

function download_send_headers($filename) {
    // disable caching
    $now = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s");
    header("Expires: Tue, 03 Jul 2001 06:00:00 GMT");
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate");
    header("Last-Modified: {$now} GMT");

    // force download  
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");

    // disposition / encoding on response body
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename={$filename}");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
}

download_send_headers("wishlist_details" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
echo array2csv($csvGenerate);
die();
```